# django rest swagger nested serializers not rendered properly

Tags: django-rest-swagger

[image]

[image]

The swagger ui doesn't render the detail fields in Title object, how can i fix this?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Carl - Were you able to debug the issue?